# Enabling Data API with Java CDK for Serverless Aurora V2

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-aurora-serverless

I currently reate my Serverless V2 Aurora cluster with

```
DatabaseCluster cluster = DatabaseCluster.Builder.create(...)
```

and I'm trying to enable the new Data API for V2 but I don't see any way to do it with CDK.

My current builder has e.g. attributes for serverlessV2MinCapacity() but none for the Data API. There is a ServerlessCluster Builder with a function for enabling the Data API but it looks to be for V1 since it doesn't cover serverlessV2MinCapacity() & co?

What would be the way to create a V2 cluster with Data API enabled?